# D3 Parsing Error

Tags: d3.js

This is likely a very easy question (but I'm new to D3 and trying to go through some of the examples to get a better understanding of how it works).  I'm trying to modify one of the base examples for D3 (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367).  I've basically kept everything the same... I'm just trying to use a different csv file with my own data (vs. the S&P 500 stock data).  In the example file, the csv file has a date (month year) and a stock price.  In my data, I have a UTC time stamp and a light value (between 0-1000).  Here's a small example of the csv:

```
date, light
2013-01-01T09:00:00.000Z,554.22
2013-01-01T09:01:00.000Z,480.83
2013-01-01T09:02:00.000Z,433.19
2013-01-01T09:03:00.000Z,596.89
2013-01-01T09:04:00.000Z,421.78
2013-01-01T09:05:00.000Z,461.23
2013-01-01T09:06:00.000Z,560.04
```

When, I run my code I get an error in the console window saying I have a parsing error (not sure if it's getting caught up in parsing the data or the light value)...  Does anyone see a problem with how I'm setting up the csv file (or how I might be parsing it incorrectly)?  Here's the D3 code I'm working with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brush);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.light); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.light); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.csv("Light.csv", function(error, data) {
  console.log(data);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    //d.light = +d.light;
    //console.log(d);
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.light; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", area);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
});

function brush() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the header of your csv file, the "light" header has an extra space in front of it. That leads to processing problems with d3.csv.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.light = +d.light;  // won't be able to access the light column data with the space
  d.light = d[' light']; // this would work if you can't fix the header at the csv source
});
```

Hmmm, maybe I'll submit a patch to d3 to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting that error because of your time format specification -- there is no `%L` placeholder (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format)). This should work.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z").parse;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  I tried modifying the format declaration, but I'm still getting a parsing error.  You'll notice that right after I get the data from the csv file, that I print the data to the console.  When I look at this data, it print light: "554.22"
date: Tue Jan 01 2013 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)... however, the date object has a little arrow next to it (which you can expand) and when I do, it says __proto__: Invalid Date.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, you'll have to help me a bit here -- where does it get the parse error?

Comment: It's kind of hard to say.  The error message is really long (like 50 lines long).  It basically says: Error: Problem parsing... then it has a whole bunch of numbers and NAN stuff, and then at the bottom of the error message it points to d3.v3.min.js:1  Does this help?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your path generation. Try checking `data` after it has been processed to make sure that the names and values are what they should be. In particular check that the "light" values are numbers and not strings.

Comment: It's possible they could be strings.  The light value is represented by light:"554.22", whereas I would assume if its a number it would say light:554.22.  How do I cast the string to a number when I read in the csv file?

Comment: I just tried adding the line:  d.light = parseFloat(d.light);  but this seems to parse it as NAN.  Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Just uncomment the line `d.light = +d.light;`.

Comment: Uncommenting it doesn't seem to do much.  I still get the parsing errors and it still says light:"554.22" and date:Tue Jan 01 2013 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time).  Like I said, I tried changing that line to: d.light = parseFloat(d.light); but this didn't work either.  Would it help if I copy the entire error message (which is really long and pretty hard to decipher)

Comment: I think my test csv file was a little big for debugging purposes (had about 540 entries).  So, I pared it down to just four entries to get a more manageable error message.  So, this is what I get now:

Object {date: Tue Jan 01 2013 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), light: "554.22"}

Object {date: Tue Jan 01 2013 09:01:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), light: "480.83"}

Object {date: Tue Jan 01 2013 09:02:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), light: "433.19"}

Object {date: Tue Jan 01 2013 09:03:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), light: "596.89"}

Comment: Error: Problem parsing d="M0,NaNC0,NaN,303.33333333333337,NaN,303.33333333333337,NaNS606.6666666666667,NaN,606.6666666666667,NaNS910,NaN,910,NaNL910,390C859.4444444444445,390,707.7777777777778,390,606.6666666666667,390S404.4444444444445,390,303.33333333333337,390S50.555555555555564,390,0,390Z" 

Error: Problem parsing d="M0,NaNC0,NaN,303.33333333333337,NaN,303.33333333333337,NaNS606.6666666666667,NaN,606.6666666666667,NaNS910,NaN,910,NaNL910,50C859.4444444444445,50,707.7777777777778,50,606.6666666666667,50S404.4444444444445,50,303.33333333333337,50S50.555555555555564,50,0,50Z" d3.v3.min.js:1

Comment: I played around with loading your csv data and found the space after the comma in the header line would give problems with the light field. Removing the space made things run much smoother.

Comment: That was it!  I had space in the first line (basically: date, light)... but I shouldn't have used a space.  It seems to be working now!  I'm sorry for all the silly questions and error messages.  Thanks for the help!